# create a composer package on packigist with bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, composer-php, packagist

I have be building my own framework for self education and am trying to set it up to work with composer. I uploaded it to [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/yamiko/lume/) and created a [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/yamiko/lume) but when I try to install it on netbeans on my windows I get a error `'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. The dependencies load and install fine and I see that twig and other packages etc has source, issue and other links. How can I set it up to work like the others?

I know some can only be installed through git but I would like to make my package available without requiring git to be global on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are under the [`source`](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#support) property.

```
"support": {
    "email": "rparker@yamiko.org",
    "issues": "http://lume-framework.yamiko.org/issues",
    "forum": "http://lume-framework.yamiko.org/forum",
    "wiki": "",
    "irc": "",
    "source": ""
},
```